# I accidently deleted some DLLs from .NET framework folders and now I get errors reading 'connectionStrings' by IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, connection-string

I already tried reinstaling .NET 4.5 and Windows Azure Tools, and getting a bit desperate that I've screwed up my Windows installation. Anyone some more ideas? I would be really grateful.

```
---------------------------
.NET Profile
---------------------------
There was an error while performing this operation.

Details: 

Filename: \\?\C:\[Path]\web.config

Line number: 38

Error: The configuration section 'connectionStrings' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration
```

**Extra Notes**

- IIS Express doesn't have problems and load perfectly
- A Console app with the same connectionStrings section also works

Comment: Reinstalling and rebooting machine should fix it.

Comment: Thanks, that is something that I like to prevent atm though, becaus it is my working machine and have a deadline coming up :/

Comment: Reinstalling .Net framework and not OS. I hope you rebooted system after reinstall .Net Fx

Comment: Can you please share your web.config file over here? So that it can be identified that which files you have deleted?

Comment: Hi @ImranBalouch, the Web.config is quite big (271 lines) and I am affraid I will expose vulnerabilities. Strange thing is: in IIS Express is works perfectly well, when I use a similar config in a console app it also works. Just not IIS

Comment: In your config file, can you try placing <clear/> tag immediately after starting the <connectionStrings> tag.

Comment: Also did you checked this URL? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/949351

Comment: I Imran, I checked that URL, but my configuration file is not encrypted. Also, the error appeared to start after deleting the DLL's and works with IIS Express. I will try the <clear /> tag, thanks again!

Comment: Try this command: `aspnet_regiis.exe -i`
It installs aspnet in iss.  Check this link for details https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.140%29.aspx?lc=1033

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the connectionStrings section handler is missing from the machine.config file.

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="connectionStrings" 
                 type="System.Configuration.ConnectionStringsSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
                 requirePermission="false"/>
    </configSections>
</configuration>
```

Do note that the file could be in one of several locations depending on what .NET framework version you are using and whether the application is 32 or 64 bit.

- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config
- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG
- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config
- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG

Also, you need to ensure that the correct .NET version exists in the `<section>` element. The simplest way is just to copy each of the machine.config files over from a known working system (assuming you haven't customized them in some way).

You could also put this right in your web.config file, but there will probably be other applications that are broken on your machine.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed there where no machine.configs at all anymore in my framework64. The problem is fixed, but now I have a different one. I guess a total reinstall of .NET might fix the problem. I'll try that later.